# Moving data from multiple unique_ptr into contiguous C-style array

Tags: c++

Over time I am receiving parts(`RdKafka::Message`) of a larger message and storing them in

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RdKafka::Message>> messageParts;
```

The `RdKafka::Message` has a raw pointer payload that I want to move into a single `shared_ptr`.  I can do this because I have the size and index into the original larger message contained in the `RdKafka::Message`.

Once I have received all parts of the larger message I want to reassemble all of the messages into a single `shared_ptr`.

My first strategy has been to allocate the total amount of memory space in a C style pointer and then `std::move` each individual `unique_ptr` part of the data into the correct section of the C style memory.  Something like this:

```
uint8_t* payload = new uint8_t[totalBytes];
for(auto& m : messageParts){
    int32_t partition = m->partition();
    size_t len = m->len();

    std::memcpy(&payload[partition], (uint8_t*)(m->payload()), len);
}
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>(payload);
```

This obviously doesn't compile but I am looking for something like this so that I can return a single pointer to all the original memory.

Comment: I can see any "obvious" reason as to why this shouldn't compile (besides maybe a missing custom deleter and switching the shared pointer type to `std::shared_ptr<std::uint8_t>`)

Comment: You probably mean `payload + partition` or `&payload[partition]` in `memcpy`.

Comment: agreed @Jarod42.  I was just looking for a better way to reassemble the memory.